# How do I create a paragraph break in Google Form help text?

Tags: google-forms

I've looked on Google's product forums, and I can't find anything. The help text field is designed for brief text, but I want to insert a mulit-paragraph article. Without paragraph breaks, I wind up with a bunch of text that's difficult to read.

Answer (score 16):

This has been bugging me for a long time and I've came up with a not so elegant but efficient solution based on Apps Script. Pavel Agarkov had the same idea! My version also works with multiple occurences and can be re-run if Google Forms removes the line breaks when you edit the text.

---

1. When editing a form, open the Script Editor from the main menu. 
   [image: Access the Script Editor menu]
2. Create a new script, replace the content with the code below. Save it and return to your form.
3. Reload the page. You will notice a new option in the main menu, looking like this
   [image: Scripts menu]
   That "Scripts" menu was added by our script. Don't use it for now, it won't do much.
4. When editing content, use fours spaces as a placeholder for line breaks. 
   [image: Four spaces]
5. Run the script from the Scripts menu. Now celebrate ‍♀️

Some things worth noting:

- You will get a permission request the first time you run the script. It's ok, read the message and do what you have to do.
- Once the line breaks are there, Google Forms, god bless its heart, will remove them every time you edit the field. Mildly infuriating. Just run the script again.

---

The script you need to use is:

```js
// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207368/

function onOpen() {
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Scripts')
    .addItem('Replace 4+ spaces with line breaks in Title and Description', 'addLineBreaks')
    .addToUi();
}

function addLineBreaks() {
  var theForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var theQuestions = theForm.getItems();
  var thePlaceholder = new RegExp(/\s{4,99}|\n/, 'gi');
  for (i = 0; i < theQuestions.length; i++) {
    var theText = theQuestions[i].getHelpText();
    if (theText.search(thePlaceholder) > 0 ) {
      theQuestions[i].setHelpText(theText.replace(thePlaceholder,'    \n'));
    }
    theText = theQuestions[i].getTitle();
    if (theText.search(thePlaceholder) > 0 ) {
      theQuestions[i].setTitle(theText.replace(thePlaceholder,'    \n'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you change `thePlaceholder` to `var thePlaceholder = new RegExp(/ {4}(?![\n\r\t$])/, 'gi');` you can put multiple line breaks in.  With this regex, *each* 4 spaces will turn into a newline, and it checks to make sure there isn't already a newline there so that it doesn't keep adding newlines each time you run the script.  Also, use ` ` (space) rather than `\s` (whitespace chars) so it doesn't include anything besides spaces.

Answer (score 13):

I found that you can't do it through the editor but it is possible via the script.
Go to main menu -> script editor;
past the following code to the editor;

```js
function addLineBreaks()
{
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 
  
  // find form items you need
  var questions = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
  
  for(i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
  {
    var title = questions[i].getTitle();
    // if no replacement has been done yet
    if(title.indexOf("\n") < 0)
    {
      // this will add line break after <double space> like in markdown
      questions[i].setTitle(title.replace("  ", "  \n"));
    }
  }
}
```

then set up trigger to start this method on form open.

Comment: hey...   I think we definitely want  .indexOf  > 0 ,  no?
If you get this, maybe change :)   We can't Edit only one character :)

Comment: @MikeM - no, since this will be executed multiple times you need the replacement to be done only once. At least it was true for my case with `"B:"`

Comment: ah, I get your point...  I was thinking of other examples where the text in the string was also \n .  My bad :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I run this code and I get no CRs:

```javascript
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("What category does the project fall under?").setHelpText("http://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs\n\nThe Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Node.js helps you get a skill up and running quickly, letting you focus on skill logic instead of boilerplate code.").setChoiceValues(['API','EDUCATION', 'GENERAL', 'DATASET'])
```

Comment: as I mentioned before - each time form is edited manually - all line breaks will disappear - you have to keep replacing something and adding `\n` each time.

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this question myself for too long!
However, when you know how its simple:
Go to "Add Item"
Choose "Section Header"
This option allows you to put paragraphed text into your Form.

Answer (score 2):

As of June, 2018, the following work (but only the second option is documented):

1. Just put new lines in the description and it will be shown in the form - try using two for a paragraph.
2. If you want a bit more style - add a 'Title and Description' - see the second option in the tool bar showing 'Tᴛ'. The Title will always add extra space (even if it's empty) and will show any title as inverted, larger, text. You can disable the description if you just want a 'heading' followed by questions.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me, SO I added a unicode character https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2002 pasted 4 to 5 times and this is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bad news, but this seems impossible to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!  While in the box into which you are entering text, go to  Properties in the Developer tab.  You will get a drop-down menu.  At the bottom of the menu is "Plain Test Properties" with a check box for "Allow carriage returns (multiple paragraphs).

Comment: where do i find the developer tab in a google form? i cudnt find it

Answer (score 1):

This is a better solution but based on the above.  It allows you to edit the form which amazingly the above solutions don't:

```
// Version 2020-10-07a: by Dennis Bareis
//         Handles "{nl}" in form & question descriptions
//         Forms API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms
// Based on     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207368/
// This code @: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64216993/3972414
//     [0] ... -> Script Editor -> Create New Script
//     [1] Paste into script editor
//     [2] Run onOpen()
//     [3] On first run authorise script
//     [4] This adds 2 scripts under a new button in the edit form UI
//         (to the left of the "Send" button)
//     [5] Use "START" before re-editing form
//     [6] Use "END" to publish the changes
//         5&6 required as otherwise you end up with "line1Line2Line3" etc

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) 
{
        var target = this;
        return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};


//This doesn't perform the function on open, just adds it to the UI, you run when finished.
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Scripts')
    .addItem('[1] Prepare for RE-EDITING this form (restore {nl})',   'editFormStart')
    .addItem('[2] Publish the form (finished editing, remove  {nl})', 'editFormEnd')
    .addToUi();
}


function editFormStart()
{
  swapLineBreaks("\n", "{nl}")
}

function editFormEnd()
{
  swapLineBreaks("{nl}", "\n")
}


function swapLineBreaks(FromText, ToText)
{
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 
  
  // find form items you need
  var oForm     = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var questions = oForm.getItems();

  // Fix the form's description
  var formDesc = oForm.getDescription() 
  oForm.setDescription(formDesc.replaceAll(FromText, ToText))

  // Work through each question
  for(i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) 
  {
    //var QTitle = questions[i].getTitle();
    //questions[i].setTitle(  QTitle.replaceAll(FromText, ToText));
    
    var QText  = questions[i].getHelpText();
    questions[i].setHelpText(QText.replaceAll(FromText, ToText));
  }
}
```