# Inserting line breaks into a multiple choice option in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've been tasked with adjusting the formatting of a Google Form and am having some trouble. I want to add line breaks within a single instance of a multiple choice option but no matter what I try instead of creating a new line it adds another multiple choice option. I think this is happening because there is a setting for this textarea's class that is `data-disable-newlines="true"`

I've found another thread that is close but it addresses help and Title text, not the text of a answer itself.

[How do I create a paragraph break in Google Form help text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207368/how-do-i-create-a-paragraph-break-in-google-form-help-text/61620464#61620464)

Here is the code from that thread I was trying to use:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Scripts')
    .addItem('Replace 4+ spaces with line breaks in Title and Description', 'addLineBreaks')
    .addToUi();
}

function addLineBreaks() {
  var theForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var theQuestions = theForm.getItems();
  var thePlaceholder = new RegExp(/\s{4,99}|\n/, 'gi');
  for (i = 0; i < theQuestions.length; i++) {
    var theText = theQuestions[i].getHelpText();
    if (theText.search(thePlaceholder) > 0 ) {
      theQuestions[i].setHelpText(theText.replace(thePlaceholder,'    \n'));
    }
    theText = theQuestions[i].getTitle();
    if (theText.search(thePlaceholder) > 0 ) {
      theQuestions[i].setTitle(theText.replace(thePlaceholder,'    \n'));
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is an example of what I'm trying to target vs. what is being targeted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBNWs.png)

Any guidance is much appreciated, I've spent more time on this than I would like to admit.

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce the issue. 1st problem: your marker for a newline is based on 4 or more spaces. When I tried to get the choices values, multiple spaces were changed to a single space (you can also verify that if you view your form, it will remove extra spaces in the choices). Next, I tried to use a different marker "*****", I was able to successfully create a choices with a new line. However, when I set the new choices values in the multiple choice item, the new line was also replaced by a space.

Comment: You can file a feature request here if you want https://issuetracker.google.com