# Break line in google form title and description

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I created a google form and am trying to insert a line in a title. I found scripts for inserting lines in questions but couldnt find any script for title.
I know that i need to use /n in script section to insert a line but dont know how to do it actually and what else script i need.

I need to write in my title lets say A /n B /n C

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to show what you tried. P.S. Only use tags that refers to stuff mentioned in the question... it's not clear why [tag:google-sheets] was included.

Comment: You might wanna check out this post similar to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207368/how-do-i-create-a-paragraph-break-in-google-form-help-text/61620464#61620464

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `/` slash in wrong in your question. It's got to be `\`. Plug this into your app script and you should be able to see it work...

```
function quickTest() {
  const aForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const doubleLine = "first line\nsecond line"

  aForm.setTitle(doubleLine)
  aForm.setDescription(doubleLine);
  var aItem = aForm.getItems()[0];
  aItem.setTitle(doubleLine);
  aItem.setHelpText(doubleLine);
}
```

[image]